# JQuery ajax call on android

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, ajax

I have some html and javascript code running on a WIFI module that runs a webserver. At a certain point, a jquery ajax call is done like so:

```
reqData = JSON.stringify({FileName: L_JSON_FILENAME, CmdArr: [["read", "cmduart", "data"]]});
jQuery.ajax('' + _szFileRequest,
        {
            data: reqData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ReturnedColumn = handleData(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                ReturnedColumn = "error";
            }
        });
```

Now I want to do the same thing on an android app.

I am currently working in Android Studio.

I have read something about a JSONobject and using toString.
But I have also read about using AsyncHttpClient and using RequestParams.

What is the best way to accomplish this call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the webpages were on a webserver I only needed to access that webserver. Connecting to it's WIFI and have a webview open the webpage on the webserver did the trick for me.

The JavaScript runs on the webserver and can easily execute the ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

I use Retrofit : 
https://square.github.io/retrofit/
It's perfect to make HTTP calls, and it has converters, to ease conversions from JSON, XML, and other format to java

Some examples : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm new to Java and I don't understand most of the things I can find about Retrofit.
Would I use Retrofit to do the JSON.stringify only, or would I use it to do the whole jQuery.ajax call? And how exactly?

Comment: Well, Retrofit alone can fulfill all you needs. 
First, it is an HTTP Client, so you do all yout HTTP calls, manage authentication, etc.
Next, it can easily map JSON data to POJOs (Plain Old Java Object).
There are tons of examples/tutorials on the net, and even more, many videos on youtube :  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=retrofit+2

Of course you may need to spend some time on java first, to get used with annotation for example.